# How to subset times in R

Tags: r, posixct

In R I have data

```
USER   BIRTH
11     "2013-01-11 22:31:11"
121    "2014-12-26 04:07:35"
...
```

I want to create a new data set `data_new` that contain all `USER` in the time 10 o'clock to 11 o'clock. 
The types of `USER` and `BIRTH` are strings/characters. I tried this:

```
data_new= data$BIRTH > as.POSIXct("10:00:00", format="%H:%M:%S")
& data$BIRTH < as.POSIXct("11:00:00", format="%H:%M:%S")
```

but here R gives we FALSE for all entries, so this don't work.
How can I solve this?

**Update**

Say I want to find the number of users for all hours. I use the answer and try this

```
u=c()
for(j in 1:24)  {
data_new=data[times > "00:00:00"+(j-1) & times < "01:00:00"+j ,]
#saving the number of users in vector u
u[j]=dim(data_new)[1]
}
```

but R can't figure out the term `"00:00:00"+(j-1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df` is your data frame:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'USER   BIRTH
11     "2013-01-11 22:31:11"
121    "2014-12-26 04:07:35"
121    "2014-12-26 10:07:35"
121    "2014-12-26 11:07:35"
121    "2014-12-26 10:38:35"', header = T)

df$BIRTH <- ymd_hms(df$BIRTH)

times <- strftime(df$BIRTH, format = "%H:%M:%S")
df[times > "10:00:00" & times < "11:00:00",]
```

Output:

```
  USER               BIRTH
3  121 2014-12-26 10:07:35
5  121 2014-12-26 10:38:35
```

Comment: What makes you believe this works? R doesn't do math with characters.

Comment: @user6678274: A potential issue with this solution is that it relies on the collation order of your locale, which may possibly provide unexpected results. See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: How would you subset so you get all data for a fixed year, 2016 fe.

Comment: Something like `df[year(df$BIRTH) == 2016,]`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do something to each subset of your data is to use the `split`-`lapply` paradigm. In this case, you would convert `data$BIRTH` to `POSIXlt` and split by the `hour` component of the `POSIXlt` object. That will give you a list where each list element contains all the data for a specific hour.

```
data <- read.csv(text = "USER,BIRTH
11,2013-01-11 22:31:11
12,2014-12-26 04:07:35
21,2014-12-26 10:07:35
121,2014-12-26 11:07:35
112,2014-12-26 10:38:35")

data_by_hour <- split(data, as.POSIXlt(data$BIRTH)$hour)
```

Then you can use `lapply` (or `sapply`) to do whatever you want to each of those subsets. To count the number of observations per hour:

```
# number of observations for each hour
sapply(data_by_hour, nrow)
 4 10 11 22 
 1  2  1  1
```

You can also do this with xts.

```
library(xts)
# Create xts object from 'data' data.frame
# Note: xts objects are based on a matrix, so you cannot have columns with
#       mixed types like you can with a data.frame.
x <- xts(data["USER"], as.POSIXct(data$BIRTH))
period.apply(x, endpoints(x, "hours"), nrow)
#                     USER
# 2013-01-11 22:31:11    1
# 2014-12-26 04:07:35    1
# 2014-12-26 10:38:35    2
# 2014-12-26 11:07:35    1
```

Note that you can do time-of-day subsetting with xts. It avoids potential locale-related collation order issues caused by using logical operators on character strings.

```
x["T10:00/T11:00"]
#                     USER
# 2014-12-26 10:07:35   21
# 2014-12-26 10:38:35  112
```

Comment: Thanks but Im not sure about the notation here. For a large dataset I should not paste in all the data.

Comment: @user6678274: you wouldn't paste in all your data and read it using the `text` argument of `read.zoo` (or `read.table`). I did that so you could run my code. I've edited my answer to start from your `data` object. R gave that error because you didn't load the xts package, so I added that to my answer too.

Comment: This is working. Say I want all the results for all hours 1,..,24 it's hard for me to make a for-loop since I have to iterate over a string. Otherwise one should write all the 24 cases manually.

Comment: @user6678274: I didn't see that your actual question was to do something with each hourly subset.

Comment: as.POSIXct("2016-01-02 00:02:45") runs fine in R but as.POSIXct("11:25:26") dont work - R say ERROR character string is not in a standard unambigous format. What can I do to solve it?